# How can i make pip install my package to PATH?

Tags: python, pip

I have followed the pip tutorial at http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html. But when i run `pip install mypackage` it installs the source code into `site-packages` under my Python folder.

How can i make it install into path, so i can run `$ mypackage`?

That is, I would like to be able to use my python package as a regular binary application. Right now i can `cd` into the folder under `site-packages` and run `chmod +x mypackage.py`, then `./mypackage.py` to run it. But i would like to be able to run it from any directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you do it by defining `console scripts` in your package configuration. Then you install the package with pip just as you have done before (or better in a `virtualenv`), but during the installation a link will be created in the `bin` directory to the console script that you have configured. See e.g. http://calvinx.com/2012/09/09/python-packaging-define-an-entry-point-for-console-commands/

Comment: No link in the meaning of file system link is being created. There's Python *wrapper* script being created which imports entry point and runs it.